# WaitForSingleObject and max. waiting threads

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I just noticed the following phrase in one the Intel's articles:

> One disadvantage of WaitForSingleObject is that it will always obtain
>   a kernel lock, so it enters privileged mode (ring 0) whether the lock
>   is achieved or not. This API also enters the Windows kernel even if a
>   0 timeout is specified. **Another disadvantage of this method of locking
>   is that it can only handle 64 threads attempting to place a lock on an
>   object at once**

If I understood it correctly, this code has a UB in it:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define THREAD_COUNT 100

HANDLE g_mutex;

DWORD WINAPI foo(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
  WaitForSingleObject(g_mutex, INFINITE);
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  g_mutex = CreateMutex(
    NULL,              // default security attributes
    FALSE,             // initially not owned
    NULL);             // unnamed mutex
  if (g_mutex == NULL)
  {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  WaitForSingleObject(g_mutex, INFINITE);

  std::vector<HANDLE> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++)
  {
    HANDLE th = CreateThread(
      NULL,       // default security attributes
      0,          // default stack size
      (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)foo,
      NULL,       // no thread function arguments
      0,          // default creation flags
      NULL);      // don't receive thread identifier
    if (th == NULL)
    {
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    threads.push_back(th);
  }

  while (true)
  {
    Sleep(100);
  }
}
```

because it forces more than 64 threads to wait for the specific resource (in my case, mutex).

I know that this limitation exists for the [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) function, but in the article it says about the [WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Am I right?

Comment: That quote is inaccurate. The limit is that up to 64 *objects* may be waited on by a single call to `WaitForMultipleObjects`. There's no limit on the number of threads that can simultaneously call one of the wait functions.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Are you sure?

Comment: I could believe that the wait becomes less efficient if there are many threads waiting for the same object, but I doubt that it fails completely.